# Working with unicode in python

Tags: python, utf-8, encode

I connect to a mysql database using pymysql and after executing a request I got the following string: `\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0`.

This should be 5 characters in utf8, but when I do `print s.encode('utf-8')` I get this: `╨╝╨░╤А╨║╨░`. The string looks like byte representation of unicode characters, which python fails to recognize.

So what do I do to make python process them properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to `decode` (not `encode`) to get a unicode string from a byte string.

```
>>> s = '\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'
>>> us = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> print us
марка
```

Note that you may not be able to `print` it because it contains characters outside ASCII. But you should be able to see its value in a Unicode-aware debugger. I ran the above in IDLE.

**Update**

It seems what you actually have is this:

```
>>> s = u'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'
```

This is trickier because you first have to get those bytes into a bytestring before you call `decode`. I'm not sure what the "best" way to do that is, but this works:

```
>>> us = ''.join(chr(ord(c)) for c in s).decode('utf-8')
>>> print us
марка
```

Note that you should of course be decoding it *before* you store it in the database as a string.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried decode I got an error saying "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)".  Must be because the string was represented as `u\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0`

Comment: `print s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` also worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Mark is right: you need to decode the string.  Byte strings become Unicode strings by decoding them, encoding goes the other way.  This and many other details are at [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain?](http://bit.ly/unipain).

Comment: I've fallen foul of this in the past - and just try to remember that one "decodes" bytes, but "encodes" text.